# Celery failing with ValueError on Python 3.8

Tags: django, django-celery, python-3.8

I upgraded my environment to python 3.8 and now my celery (tried v4.4.2 to 4.4.7) is not able to start with the following error:

> ValueError: invalid width -2 (must be > 0)

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a solution [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5761#issuecomment-628585395)! You need to set a new ENV variable:

`COLUMNS=80`

Hope this helps some other persons as well!